# What is the probability that none of the girls sits together with a boy on a bench?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Q: $16$ kids, $8$ boys and $8$ girls, are going on a train trip. Conveniently enough, the train has precisely $8$ benches and each bench seats precisely $2$ kids. The teacher assigns each kid at random to one of the $8$ benches. What is the probability that none of the girls sits together with a boy on a bench?

I'm thinking that'd be $\dfrac{\binom{16}{8} \cdot 8!}{16!}$. Not quite sure though, help appreciated.

Comment: You want all boys separated from all girls. There are $\binom{16}{8}$ ways to pick $8$ kids. Thus the probability of picking only boys is $\frac{1}{\binom{16}{8}}$. Continue it from here.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the girls sit together with a boy, then all the girls sit with another girl. Choose the four benches the girls will sit in. Seat the girls in these benches, and then seat the boys in the rest. Divide by the total number of ways to seat them.